# Can a trauma card meet the requirements for victory

Tags: mansions-of-madness

There is a winning condition for the keeper that states that a Mi Go monster must kill an investigator.

If the Mi Go monster did damage to an investigator and then I trigger a Trauma card that kills the investigator based on the damage dealt by the Mi Go, is that still considered as meeting the winning condition?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's ever explicitly mentioned, but I'd say no. Thematically it probably makes sense, but from a rules point of view, it seems logical that it would need to be damaged received directly from the Mi Go.